Are the Zero Article and the Definite Article Sometimes Interchangeable in Plural Count Nouns?
Consider the following two quotes containing the noun phrase 'Nike Dunks' (a collection of shoes), in which we assume that we are referring to the entire category of these shoes, not a specific sub-category or a selection of Nike Dunks previously mentioned:

[1] Nike Dunks are widely popular amongst footwear fans.


[2] The Nike Dunks are widely popular amongst footwear fans.

My question refers to the usage of the definite article, 'the,' and the zero article (or the absence of any article). I've noticed that in certain plural count noun phrases, the two versions are often used interchangeably without any obvious difference in meaning.
Could someone shed some light on what the difference is (if there is one)? There are several similar questions, but I don't think they address this nuance of interchangeability without altering meaning.

Compare British people are widely popular amongst TEFL students, which is essentially the same construction. There's not really a problem with The British people are..., but as a rule I'd advise against including the article. It doesn't really affect the meaning either way.

Is that an actual example you've seen? Where did you see it?

@StuartF, those were my examples. For context, I'm a native speaker, not a learner, so they should be perfectly idiomatic.

I've found an official source that addresses this exact issue: 'The use of articles with common nouns' (p. 265) in A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language.
Here's what the authors have to say about the interchangeability of different noun phrases (with and without articles):

Singular or plural, definite or indefinite, can often be used without appreciable difference of meaning in generic contexts.

They go on to give these examples (with 2 and 3 following the same structures as my examples):

[1] A German is a good musician.


[2] Germans are good musicians.


[3] The Germans are good musicians.


[4] A tiger can be dangerous.


[5] Tigers can be dangerous.


[6] The tiger can be dangerous.


Nike doesn't use article "the" with their brand name. Otherwise no issue.

I think you're looking for something that doesn't exist. There really is no difference between the two. Perhaps you could say that using the article is slightly more formal than not using it, but that would be the extent of it.

You may be right, but another example that gives me reason to think there's a subtle difference is 'Elves' and 'the Elves' in Tolkien's The Lord of the Rings. He often refers to the collective species as 'the Elves.' For example (and this is my own sentence, not something Tolkien wrote), he might say, 'The Elves started to leave Middle-earth.' Saying 'Elves started to leave Middle-earth' isn't the same, as it doesn't necessarily imply all of them. I admit there's more implicit difference here than in my examples, but it makes me wonder.

In that example, it goes back to the standard rules. If you say "The Elves started to leave," you're referring to a specific group of elves. If you say "Elves started to leave," you're referring to elves in general.
